# Are there available solutions to the Virginia Tech Regional Mathematics Contest before years 1987?

Tags: real-analysis

Right now I'm stuck on a problem from a competition from nineteen eighty one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0T2Z.png)

I only have an idea on how to solve it and I can't look at the solutions so I'm kinda stuck.

Any hint or advice would be incredible, thank you!

*Edit: I apologize for my bad post. I'm rather new to Stack Exchange. I didn't realize that inserting Latex was so simple.

Here's the question typed up:

(VTRMC 1981). For which real numbers b does the function $f(x)$, defined by the conditions $f(0) = b$
and $f′ = 2 f −x$, satisfy $f(x) > 0$ for all $x ≥ 0$?

As for my attempts at solving this problem, I have considered that $b\not = \mathbb{R}^-$,and the minimum (it can't be maximum) of $f$ is at $f' = 2f-x = 0$ -> $x/2 = f$ where $b = 0$ here. I have a really thought of a method to use this information, so I moved on and tried redefining f and f', but the idea failed there.

Now, I'm feeling stuck and I'm not quite sure where to head now. I have no idea what theorems to use, what method, what direction...

Thank you so much for your time in reading this!

Comment: There are two things wrong with this post. One, there is.nothing in that image that cannot be typed into the question and two, you have shown no effort in trying to solve it yourself.

Comment: Write your idea, then we are open to help you.

Comment: @John Douma Thank you for your advice. I've edited my post and taken it!

Comment: @user376343 Thank you for your reply! I hope I've done better!

Comment: That is a textbook differential equation. Are people taking that contest supposed to know, or not to know ODE? That looks like a bad problem for a competition. For people with the knowledge it is too simple, no creativity required. The ones without the knowledge have work to do. Its solutions is $f(x)=(b-1/4)e^{2x}+x/2+1/4$. There are many methods that solve this differential equation. All routine computations.

Comment: For example, if the equation were $f'=2f$, would you know how to solve it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I really didn't consider a differential equations method. But looking back on it now it definitely is a possibility for this competition. This competition problem is also an older one so it might not be the most complicated which would explain why it's relatively simple for you.

Comment: I'm definitely going to look back and try to use differential equations methods to solve it! Just need to do some review! Thank you so much!

Comment: I solved it got the same answer! $b\geq1/4$